# Convert dataframe column into binary

Tags: python, pandas

My `crm` data frame contains a column "Reconciled" with numbers from 0 to 130.

I want to convert this column into 0 or 1.
If the value is 0, keep 0, otherwise change to 1.

```
crm['Reconciled'] = crm['Reconciled'].where(crm['Reconciled'] > 0, 1)
```

Now:

```
crm['Reconciled'].describe()
```

Returns:

```
count     138234
unique         1
top            1
freq      138234
Name: Reconciled, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hera are alternatives for binary:

```
crm['Reconciled'] = (crm['Reconciled'] > 0).astype(int)
crm['Reconciled'] = (crm['Reconciled'] > 0).view('i1')
crm['Reconciled'] = np.where(crm['Reconciled'] > 0, 1, 0)
```